# X-axis and Y-axis reversed in transitions CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm using transitions with transforms in my web page but I've noticed something strange. Generally, on the coordinate system , X is positioned horizontally , and Y is positioned vertically.

[image]

In my code when I use transition + transform (rotateX) it rotates it vertically ( which in coordinate system is horizontal ) , and when I use transition + transform ( rotateY) , it rotates it horizontally ( which in coordinate system is vertical).

I am little confused about that.Didn't find any answers about this curious question. Is the confusing coming from that , I'm rotating them on 360 degrees or so..

There's a jsfiddle:

```css
.workSheets{
 text-align: center;
 padding-top:20px;
}

.workBoxes{
 display:inline-block;
 height:240px;
 width:240px;
 margin-left:5px;
 margin-right:5px;
    
    color:white;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serifcursive;
}
.secondArticle{
 background-color:#f6f6f6;
}
.design{
 background-color:#10c6fc;
    background-image: url('../img/monitor.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;    
    
    -webkit-transition:transform 2s;
    -o-transition:transform 2s;
    -moz-transition:transform 2s;
    transition:transform 2s;
}

.design:hover{
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    transform:rotateY(360deg);
}


.development{
 background-color: #835aeb;
    background-image: url('../img/wand.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    
    -webkit-transition:transform 2s;
    -o-transition:transform 2s;
    -moz-transition:transform 2s;
    transition:transform 2s;

}

.development:hover{
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateY(360deg);
    transform:rotateY(360deg);
}

.testing{
 background-color:#002453;
    background-image: url('../img/deliver.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    
    -webkit-transition:transform 2s;
    -o-transition:transform 2s;
    -moz-transition:transform 2s;
    transition:transform 2s;
}

.testing:hover{
    -webkit-transform:rotateX(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotateX(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateX(360deg);
    transform:rotateX(360deg);
}


.launch{
 background-color:#ff2b4a;
    background-image: url('../img/plane.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    
    -webkit-transition:transform 2s;
    -o-transition:transform 2s;
    -moz-transition:transform 2s;
    transition:transform 2s;
}

.launch:hover{
    -webkit-transform:rotateX(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotateX(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateX(360deg);
    transform:rotateX(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="workSheets">
                    <div class="workBoxes design">
                        <h3 class="boxesFont">DESIGN</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="workBoxes development">
                        <h3 class="boxesFont">DEVELOPMENT</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="workBoxes testing">
                        <h3 class="boxesFont">TESTING</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="workBoxes launch">
                        <h3 class="boxesFont">LAUNCH</h3>
                    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well I see that's correct behaviour, when you have transform: rotateY it will rotate from left to right or bacwards as the line of rotation is vertical and so on. For me its totally understandable. here you have the same behaviour in examples http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transforms/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read all about transforms in-depth in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function). there is a very informative description there about transforms.

as written in that page, the `rotateX` function  moves the element around the abscissa

> The rotateX()CSS function defines a transformation that moves the element **around the abscissa** without deforming it. The amount of movement is defined by the specified angle; if positive, the movement will be clockwise, if negative, it will be counter-clockwise.
>
> The axis of rotation passes by the origin, defined by `transform-origin` CSS property.
>
> rotateX(a)is a shorthand for `rotate3D(1, 0, 0, a)`